# Please give me one example of pandas.DataFrame related to copy arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax, dtype

This is the syntax of pandas.DataFrame(data, index, columns,dtype, copy). I understood the arguments of data, index, and  dtype but I do not understand the arguments of copy in the syntax. Please give me an example of the syntax related to copy. Thank you in advance!

I do not understand the argument of copy in pandas.DataFrame(data, index, columns,dtype, copy)

Answer (score 1):

As a understand it, a copy=True buily dataframe makes a complete separated instance of the data and indexes. When the copy argument is **False**, if the data originally used to built de dataframe is changed, the dataframe itself changes too, like it's a reference, a pointer of sorts. If copy is **True**, than the dataframe is completely independent from the original data used to built it.
Made this little code test for you to see it happening:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

original_data = np.random.randint(10, size=(2, 2))

not_copied_df = pd.DataFrame(original_data, copy= False)
copied_df = pd.DataFrame(original_data, copy= True)
print('FIRST STEP')
print(not_copied_df)
print('------------')
print(copied_df)

# making a change to original data
original_data[0 ,0] = 5678

print('------------')
print('SECOND STEP')
print(not_copied_df)
print('------------')
print(copied_df)
```

Comment: I understood your explanation. I checked your code and worked very well. Again, I thank you so much. Have a nice day!